# Expert iptables help needed?

Tags: firewall, iptables

After a detailed analysis, I collected these details.

I am under a UDP Flood which is more of application dependent. I run a Game-Server and an attacker is flooding me with "getstatus" query which makes the GameServer respond by making the replies to the query which cause output to the attacker's IP as high as 30mb/s and server lag.

Here are the packet details,

**Packet starts with 4 bytes 0xff and then getstatus. 

Theoretically, the packet is like "\xff\xff\xff\xffgetstatus "**

Now that I've tried a lot of iptables variations like state and rate-limiting along side but those didn't work. Rate Limit works good but only when the Server is not started. As soon as the server starts, no iptables rule seems to block it.

Anyone else got more solutions? someone asked me to contact the provider and get it done at the Network/Router but that looks very odd and I believe they might not do it since that would also affect other clients.

---

Responding to all those answers, I'd say:

Firstly, its a VPS so they can't do it for me. Secondly, I don't care if something is coming in but since its application generated so there has to be a OS level solution to block the outgoing packets. At least the outgoing ones must be stopped.

Secondly, its not Ddos since just 400kb/s input generates 30mb/s output from my GameServer. That never happens in a D-dos. Asking the provider/hardware level solution should be used in that case but this one is different. And Yes, Banning his IP stops the flood of outgoing packets but he has many more IP-Addresses as he spoofs his original so I just need something to block him automatically.

Even tried a lot of Firewalls but as you know they are just front-ends to iptables so if something doesn't work on iptables, what would the firewalls do?

These were the rules I tried,

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DDOS --rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 5 --name DDOS --rsource -j DROP
```

It works for the attacks on un-used ports but when the server is listening and responding to the incoming queries by the attacker, it never works.

---

Okay Tom.H, your rules were working when I modified them somehow like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m length --length 1:1024 -m recent --set --name XXXX --rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m string --string "xxxxxxxxxx" --algo bm --to 65535 -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 15 --name XXXX --rsource -j DROP
```

They worked for about 3 days very good where the string "xxxxxxxxx" would be rate-limited, blocked if someone flooded and also didn't affect the clients. But just today, I tried updating the chain to try to remove a previously blocked IP so for that I had to flush the chain and restore this rule ( iptables -X and iptables -F ), some clients were already connected to servers including me. So restoring the rules now would also block some of the clients string completely while some are not affected. So does this mean I need to restart the server or why else would this happen because the last time the rules were working, there was no one connected?

Comment: What rate-limiting rules have you tried?

Comment: some qos rules could clear this up. and stop one ip/user taking up a unfair amount of resources. you can do this for both inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: Tried something like this:

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DDOS --rsource 
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 5 --name DDOS --rsource -j DROP

It works for the attacks on non-used ports but when the server is listening and responding to the queries, it never works.

Comment: @AsadMoeen it doesnt work when the server is started because youre using `--state NEW`. UDP is stateless so connection tracking on it is fuzzy. So it sees consecutive packets to an open port as being the same connection, and thus state is not new.

Comment: So what else should I use?

Comment: I also tried something like this mentioned elsewhere as a solution to such packet:

iptables -A INPUT -p UDP -m recent --set --name getstatus
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP -m string --algo bm --string "getstatus" -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 20 --name getstatus -j DROP

Comment: I suspect that servers only send getstatus requests during connection phases, hence forcing all your clients to reconnect revealed that the rule had not been fully tested.

Comment: I would consider splitting the rule into 2, so you can add a LOG line in between.

Comment: What I tested is that, 

On machine restart, the rules worked perfectly ( blocking the flood & allowing the normal clients ) but as soon as any other rule went into the chain like *allowing some IP or denying someone*, the rules would deny those strings "getstatus" for all connected clients at that time for some duration after which I saw it working again by itself so the issue only happens for some-time when entering a new rule. 

So should I just -j LOG first and then -j DROP and put out the log lines here?

Comment: paste the problem iptables output `iptables --list -v -n` into a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and add the link as a comment. (ideally show `iptables --list -v -n` before and after the problem.)

Comment: Okay I will firstly connect to my server and then take a current "iptables --list -v -n" output, then I will add a new iptables line which make those rules block the connected clients for a while during which I will take a "iptables --list -v -n" output again.

Comment: @TomH Okay I maybe understand the problem now, although no solution. What I thought was "iptables rules reconfiguration" causing the problem was actually something else. 

Here were the set of working rules, this is basically an output of my **/etc/iptables.save** file : [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/897399/) 

And here is an output of **iptables --list -v -n** : [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/897393/)

Now I connected to my Application server, reconfigured some rules and they were still working for all the clients and me. **Continued**

Comment: **Continual**
 So now I used a test machine to flood it with the given strings and now where the iptables rules blocked the attacker pretty well they also started blocking the **connected clients and me** which had no relation to the attacker at all. Here the word **connected** has some significance because as soon as I or the client disconnected from the application server, **iptables** were no longer blocking that specific client so here is an output after that : [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/897406/) **So it appears, when the attacker flooded, iptables blocked the connected clients**

Comment: **Also** As soon as the client connects after disconnecting again, he starts facing the same issue and iptables are blocking the strings to him again.

Comment: first off, you need to add the `0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       x.x.x.x          0.0.0.0/0` line above the DROP line, as its the first rule to match wins. Hence they never hit. use `iptables -I INPUT` rather than `iptables -A INPUT`

Comment: Okay I did: **iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT** and these were the new rules : http://paste.ubuntu.com/897429/ 

Now the attacker wasn't blocked at all.

Comment: do `iptables -L -n -v` i want to see the counters and also paste your ruleset, or config file.

Comment: also those ACCEPT rules are still at the end in your output.

Comment: also you don't seem to have set a target on some of the rules.

Comment: Here is that file : http://paste.ubuntu.com/897439/ it contains both the output of **iptables -L -n -v** and the saved config file. I also tried removing the ACCEPT from the output to make it simple to contain only two rules ( entered in order ) : http://paste.ubuntu.com/897441/

This wouldn't block the attack so now I tried something like : http://paste.ubuntu.com/897442/ This would block the attack but cause the same issue that connected clients are getting blocked.

Comment: in your config file, or script do the `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT`  rules first, and the DROP later

Comment: Ok, this one here -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/897441/ is going to INSERT an ACCEPT rule at the first index and so wont do anthing

Comment: I tried both the variations as posted above in the links, one worked to completely accept everything including the attack ( since the ACCEPT all was on top )  and the other one denied the connected clients.

Comment: your ruleset is totally broken. - http://paste.ubuntu.com/897439/  there is no way that can work for quite a few reasons. If you want to use the recent module then you need to reread about all the options you have set - http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: If lets say, I just want this rule in the chain to work for everyone. So how do you say I must modify this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/897464/ to add solely into the chain and be working for everyone

Comment: **Also**, I changed the rules altogether with the ones you mentioned but I changed the order because the order you mentioned was actually blocking "Getstatus" altogether because the DROP ALL was on the top of the chain so I changed the order to this which appears to be working and the output to the attacker reaches a max 10kb/s which I believe is bearable. http://paste.ubuntu.com/897488/ Is this fine to go?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/897515/

Comment: Works **Perfect**. Thanks a lot! 

And btw on a side note, what does the **-A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 "0x1c=0xffffffff" -j ACCEPT** actually do? It could work without that too? And if I want to set that to each port in a range lets say 20100:20900 so that hitcount for each port in the range is 20 instead of all ports, how do I achieve that? multiport is an option but that would require us to specify each port.

Comment: ALso, tcpdump sees all traffic, hence that you can see traffic in tcpdump **DOES NOT MEAN** that the **iptables is not working** tcpdump sees all the traffic even the blocked INPUT traffic.  see this diagram http://i.szoter.com/62301dd6bc7199cf

Comment: Yes input is always entering the system and causing us bandwidth, these rules have actually blocked the output which was generated by my application due to the input of the flood. So once again, thanks a lot mate; finally something useful after 3 weeks of work. You made my day :D. Also if **-A INPUT -m u32 ! --u32 "0x1c=0xffffffff" -j ACCEPT** can be omitted or is always required for the rules to work and if we want to put the rule on each port in the range above, how do we use that?

Comment: I think you should close this question, and start these other questions on a new ticket.

Comment: Okay It won't give me an option so you could do it if you can.

Comment: I mean that you should select one of the answers as the correct one, so someone gets the points.

Comment: Then ask the question about the u32 module, and the port ranges in different questions, so that the answers are not buried under 20 or 30 comments.

Comment: I've read the history of this question, so I think you might consider starting another question that investigates strategies for dealing with blocking attackers that have some dynamic aspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're very nearly there, but it's possible that you've been cargo-culting someone else's work, possibly on ssh rate-limiting, without really understanding it.  Please note that I'm not criticising you: building on other people's work is an excellent idea in the free software community; but you should understand why they've done what they've done, so you don't fail to use it correctly.

I set up a test rig, using `nc` (netcat) to flood UDP traffic from a machine called bill to a machine called risby with the following lines:

```
risby% nc -l -u 12345
bill% seq 1 10000000 | nc -u risby 12345
```

This produced a very-rapidly increasing list of numbers from risby's netcat, much like the command-flooding you've been having.

But when I created two new rules for risby's iptables which filtered only UDP traffic to port 12345 **without regard for state**, it worked fine:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 12345 -m recent --set --name ddos
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp --dport 12345 -m recent --rcheck  --seconds 1 --hitcount 5 --name ddos -j DROP
```

When I re-ran the netcats, the first few packets from bill got through on risby, and the numbers climbed rapidly to about 1800, but then it stalled completely and no further traffic was received from bill.

Note that it's quite important that these rules come **early** in your iptables INPUT chain, which is why I've inserted them at lines 1 and 2 respectively.

**Edit**:

Increase the rate, and require it to be sustained for longer; perhaps `--seconds 10 --hitcount 50`?  Eventually you'll reach a threshold where few legitimate clients are affected, but the DDoS is still substantially throttled. Note that friendly-fire is always a possibility in this kind of layer-3 throttling; my own ssh server limits new connections to two per 60s window, which makes repeated scps quite slow. But it's a price I'm willing to pay, and to do better requires layer-4 throttling, which means the application has to be throttling-aware.  iptables can't help you there.

I note that `--hitcount` can take no value higher than the `ip_pkt_list_tot` parameter of the xt_recent kernel module, and if the value's exceeded an error is thrown at rule-creation time:

```
[root@risby scratch]# iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m recent --rcheck  --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 --name ddos -j DROP 
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

But this value can be set at up to 255 at module insertion time.  Following the suggestions [in this blog entry](http://arulgobi.blogspot.com/2009/08/ddos-protection-using-iptables-recent.html), it's possible to reload the module, setting the parameter explicitly:

```
[root@risby scratch]# rmmod xt_recent
[root@risby scratch]# modprobe xt_recent ip_pkt_list_tot=100
[root@risby scratch]# iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m recent --rcheck  --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 --name ddos -j DROP 
[root@risby scratch]#
```

Note how the `--hitcount 50` no longer causes errors.  You may need to flush the `INPUT` chain (`iptables -F INPUT`) and any other chains that use the `recent` module before you can remove and reinsert the `xt_recent` module.

Comment: Where this works pretty fine to block the attacker but it also blocks the clients to the server although their rate is lesser than the flooder so we might need something else and yes we're almost there. And also hitcount>20 is not accepted by iptables so I can't increase that either in-case the Game-Server players have a higher rate.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I think with the addition of the string match for the getstatus request, this additional more sophisticated rate limiting would do the trick.

Comment: Nicely combined!  I suspect you're right.

Comment: Gonna try that now!

Comment: @MadHatter regarding your ssh 60 second window, if you keep a "Master" connection open, then all your SSH traffic will reuse the existing connection, which prevents extra connects. Look at the ControlMaster and ControlPath options in ssh.

Answer (score 4):

use tcpdump to take a packet dump of the traffic.

```
tcpdump -s0 -w somefile.tcp proto udp and port NN and host www.xxx.yyy.zzz
```

inspect the packets in wireshark for the byte string you want to match;

create an iptables rule with a string match to look for the application protocol string, to allow for a certain number of those packets per second and then drop the rest of those packets

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport NN -m string  --algo bm \
 --hex-string "|ff ff ff ff 67 65 74 73 74 61 74 75 73|" \
 -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport NN -m string  --algo bm \
 --hex-string "|ff ff ff ff 67 65 74 73 74 61 74 75 73|" -j DROP
```

its lucky this is udp, because its less resource intensive to do the matching on the netfilter module...

caveats are that you are going to block all getstatus requests, unless you can find some other filter for just this source, and that you will have to do a little bit of wikipedia work to work out the correct hex representation of your match string

Comment: That probably looks good and might work but the thing is that some fair clients also use the same string "getstatus" protocol so we might have to rate-limit it for working around. And yes that is the correct hex of the string.

But I'm not sure if that would auto include anything from the end of the string because the application reads anything after "getstatus" also as getstatus so "getstatus." would also be getstatus.

So how do we rate limit inside that?

Comment: there is an article here; http://www.tty1.net/blog/2007-02-06-iptables-firewall_en.html which talks about applying rate filtering on top of particular matches.

Comment: I would try that.

But wouldn't direct rate-limiting work?
I just tried limiting all the packets on the application port to lets say 20 per second which blocked the attacker but also kind of rate-limited the clients as they started Lagging.

Comment: This is the solution.  Normal clients don't send any more then one-two getstatus packets a second, so they shouldn't be impacted by this.  Also, once they are connected to your server they no longer send getstatus packets.  It should be noted here that you are not the target of this DDoS.  They are using your server as part of a DDoS reflection attack.

Comment: Yes but the rules did not work and my clients also started Lagging so I removed them. I don't know why but maybe the hitcount/seconds are not working. I also tried a rule like "iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m length --length 40 -j DROP" and amazingly this also did not block the attacker although I could clearly see in tcpdump that packet length is a constant 40. Why wouldn't it work? or maybe when connection is established, length wont work.

Comment: And
Secondly, I have servers in 3 different locations and the same 7 IP-Addresses that change everyday are attacking all those 3 servers which makes me the target. They got IP-Spoofing and I don't know how they can use my server for reflection if it just replies to the attacker's queries.

Comment: iptables sucks for anything non-trivial. rate limiting is all about storing and checking state, iptables is just a front end to netfilter kernel module. Hence it is better at matching using filters first, and then apply rate module limits.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY! 

THANK YOU. FINALLY AFTER 10 days I have some solution.

On my other server, I dont have the string module and the provider can't enable it for me as well since its an OpenVZ VPS so now I will just try to find some way around it by looking at MadHatter's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your provier and ask them to block the traffic at the router.
This will not affect other clients as they will take the destination of the packets (=your server) into account.

Every iptables or other local approach will not be a solution, since the packets need to be dealt with anyway so they will affect your server.

Comment: so your asking him to contact the ISP everytime a dos is * detected* , i don't know who your isp is, but i'd like to be on yours! He did not say the his server is cpu bound. Qos rules can actually help flatten out out resource bottlenecks if deployed correctly.

Comment: Its a VPS so they can't do it for me.

Secondly, I don't care if something is coming in but since its application generated so there has to be a OS level solution to block the outgoing packets. At least the outgoing ones must be stopped.

Comment: Asad, you did not quite get what i am saying, it is not only about outgoing packets, even if your application is not replying to that kind of requests anymore you are still facing a large amount of incoming traffic which will eventually be too much for your server/iptables/network stack to handle, that's the whole point of a DOS Attack.
@user37899 you need to read up about DOS Attacks and Network Security, you are missing the point here.

Comment: How large is 70kb/s compared to Gigabits of Ddos?

Yes 70kb/s flood generates 2mb/s output from the server.

Comment: Did you ever experience a real DOS? 70kb/s does not even remotely qualify as a serious threat. I guess i am thinking about a much larger scale than you are.

Comment: No I just home a game-server which is under a UDP Flood. Its not a Ddos, I know in that case all we can do is either block it from the provider or use a Hardware Firewall as it will saturate your port but the only thing I'm trying to do is block the input because that input is causing the output generated from my server.

Comment: This is not a DDoS (directed at him).  It's someone using his server to attack another server. IPTables rate limiting is very, very effective in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered banning his IP (if he's not spoofing it)? What you are experiencing is known as Denial of Service. I suggest you try out OSSEC. It might help blocking the IP's the attacker is using.

Comment: if he is spoofing his ip, make sure you protocol needs a tcp connection first then only accept traffic with udp connection from the same ip address. won't work for people behind nat. :-(. If your have lots of clients behind nat, think off adding a per user session key to your protocol.

Comment: Its not Ddos since 400kb/s input generates 30mb/s output from my GameServer. That never happens in a Ddos. And Yes, Banning his IP stops the flood of outgoing packets but he has many more as he spoofs his original IP Address so I just need something to block him automatically.

Comment: you need to change your protocol so he has to login in, or create a new account. also you need to add protection and throttling methods in  your game code to stop resources hots and malicious requests. what game is this? can i play?

Comment: Soldier of Fortune 2 - 1.00

Now coding is a tough ask.